# Exporting four band TIFF for transparency (alpha channel) using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, png, band, extract-by-mask

I am using ArcMap 10.8. I try to add a fourth band with my TIFF to extract it by mask and NOT have a black box arroud with NoData values. In the end I need a four band PNG with transparency layer. From the ArcMap documentation on [Supported raster dataset file formats](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm) I got the information that ArcGIS can read, but not write a PNG with four bands.

I know that I could use other software to do the job (FME, QGIS), but I need an ArcGIS solution (Toolbox built with ModelBuilder). I need this PNG for a displaying in a browser.

Comment: Browsers should know to make black pixels transparent even with 3 band png if black is marked as nodata. Does gdalinfo show this for your png file `NoData Value=0`?

Comment: I can not mark all black Values as nodata, because I have black values in my raster too. Thats why I want to use the extract by mask tool.

Comment: I would trust that ArcMAP cannot write 4 band PNG if is is documented so. Try to find a workaround. For example, write a 4 band TIFF and convert it with GDAL. Or maybe you could update the true black pixels in the data into RGB (1,1,1) that looks black but leaves (0,0,0) free for nodata.

Comment: The question is how do I write a 4 band raster in ArcMap 10.8.?

Comment: But you wrote "In the end I need a four band PNG with transparency layer." Please confirm if TIFF is what you want.

Comment: I tried to find a tool from ArcGIS Pro for converting RGB images into RGBA but could not find any. Search from the web did not help either. You wrote you can't use GDAL (`gdalwarp -dstalpha...`) so I think that you should study the Composite Bands approach.

Comment: I build a tool in modelBuilder that extracts a tiff with a shape and then exports it to png. It works if i have a four band tiff as input, but not with three bands. I found in ArcGIS Pro the export function - "render" and "rgb erzwingen" - that can create a fourth band. Will work on it again tomorrow... But actually i need an arcmap 10.8 solution because not all of my colleges hand ArcGIS pro.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this using an export of each individual band (here's how to do [that](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-extract-a-single-band-from-a-multiple-band-raste-000029230#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20ArcGIS%20Pro%20project,click%20Export%20to%20Different%20Format%E2%80%A6.&text=to%20specify%20the%20name%20and,Click%20Run.)) and then using the [Composite Bands](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm) tool in ArcGIS.
Because this is technically a workaround, set up the tool workflow in modelbuilder to save yourself headaches later, with 4 instances of the export tool running into the Composite Bands tool and outputting the bands you need.